# How to store given values of an object to them store them in a list

Tags: java

```
public class Term {
    private int coe;//Stores coefficient 
    private int exp;//Stores exponent

    public Term(int coef, int expo)
    {
        coef = coe;
        expo = exp;
    }

    public int getCoe()
    {
        return coe;
    }

    public int getExp()
    {
        return exp;
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass the given `ints` to object `a` and then add them to a `list` of `Term` called `poly`. for instance, let `coeff = 3` and `expo = 2`. I want to store 3 and 2 into the list call `poly`. But, my object `a` is not storing the 3 and 2 keeps showing 0 for both parameters.

```
public void insert(int coeff, int expo) {
    Term a = new Term(coeff, expo);// Creates a new Term object with passed #'s

    poly.add(a);
}
```

Comment: Please add Term constructor and all other relevant code.

Comment: show the constructor; show how did you read the two values from `a`; how `poly` was declared?

Comment: Yeh the constructor is wrong, try `coe = coef`;

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of `Term` you are not assigning the fields to the parameters, you are doing the opposite! Try `coe = coef` instead.

Answer (score 1):

change the constructor as

```
public Term(int coef, int expo)
    {
         coe =coef;
         exp =expo;
    }
```

You are doing it the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are doing with the values passed in the constructor.

If you want your object to have the parameters your constructor should do this

```
public Term(int coeff, int expo){
     this.coeff = coeff;
     this.expo = expo;

     //Some thing else that you would like to do
}
```

Comment: But you need to set the private variables in some way. If you are not doing it using constructor (which is very unusual) then you need to explicitly set them using setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this you need to show us how Term and ploy are defined.

If you store the two int that are given to the constructor in internal variables of Term it should work.

Comment: I just added the Term class so that you see how everything is initialized. Assume the poly arraylist is already initialized

Comment: yes, i saw now. You are assigning the input variable to the empty private int coe and exp variables. Do it the other way round!